# Javascript within jQuery-modal ajax child Fails

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am loading modal windows via `ajax` into `jQuery-modal`.
I want to make sure the content within my modal windows are not loaded independently (directly), and if a direct request is attempted, I want them redirected to the page that loads the modal (I do this by testing for the presence of `jQuery`).

The redirect works great on the direct link, but for some reason, the added `javascript` prevents the modal window from displaying (the `ajax` calls are coming through fine, but the new modal `DIV` that is created does not take on the correct `ID` and styles `[jquery-modal blocker current]`).

This is the small bit of Javascript inside my html page that kills the modal...

```
<script>if (!(window.jQuery)){window.location.href='/';}</script>
```

FYI, I've tried placing the script inside and outside of `<DIV class="modal">` on the page that is being loaded with `ajax`. Neither version works.
I have also tried removing the actual code from the script but it appears the mere presence of the `<script>` tag is a problem for the `jquery-modal`. I've also posted this issue to the GitHub repo, but the owner claims it is an implementation error.

Comment: thanks Jimi for the edits!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of calling the javascript via a `<script>` tag, you can put it in the `<body onload=''>` and it will bypass whatever issue the  `<script>` tag causes.